# How do I debug Chrome to find out which part of my Angular 6 app is making it hang?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular6

I have an angular 6 application, however sometimes the tab it is running in (chrome 69.0.3497.81) will sometimes become unresponsive (won't close or refresh).

Chrome's task manager shows the tab as using 300%+ of the CPU for an extended period of time, and then resumes as normal.

When I run the js performance profiler, it just shows idle for the period of time it hung.

I can't reproduce the problem accurately enough to work out what is causing it

How do I get to the bottom of what is making this happen ?

Comment: Impossible to know if you don't show anything .

Comment: What do you want me to show ? my app is about 8000 LOC so obviously I couldnt post it all. I am looking for a way to debug chrome, I have no experience in doing it...

Comment: There are some extensions, not sure about the compatibility with different Angular versions, but you have Batarang, Augury, ng-inspector, angularjs inspector, and I guess there are more.

Comment: Also, you can try logging as much as you can on the console at least to get to some pattern of the things that are happening before the app freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and then go to performance tab in chrome, you should be able to see at what point of time CPU is processing stuff and you should be able to see a graph there.Hope it helps :)

Comment: thankyou for your input, it shows as idle while the tab is hung.